# Can I assign API permissions to User Assigned Managed Identities?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to assign API permissions ( such as Microsoft Graph API Permissions ) to a User Assigned Managed Identity?

I like to use a MSI or User Assigned MSI to authenticate, get an access token (bearer token) to call Microsoft Graph API or any other API I published through my App registrations.

A link to an online documentation would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

To assign **Permissions to User Managed Identity**, you can make of below PowerShell script:

```
Connect-AzureAD

$TenantID="TENANTID"
$GraphAppId = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" (Dont change this value)
$DisplayNameOfMSI="MSINAME"
$PermissionName = "Directory.Read.All"

$MSI = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$NameOfMSI'")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$GraphAppId'"
$AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | 
Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $PermissionName -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application"}

New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId -PrincipalId $MSI.ObjectId -ResourceId $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $AppRole.Id
```

[image]

In the Portal, the **Graph API permissions assigned successfully** like below:

[image]

To generate access token using User Assigned MSI, **refer** below documentation:

[Managed identities - Azure App Service | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-managed-identity?tabs=portal%2Cpowershell#connect-to-azure-services-in-app-code)

**Note** that, for obtaining a token for User Assigned MSI you must include one of the optional properties.

Comment: Like other types of applications, is there any way to do the same in the portal, not using PowerShell?

Comment: Assigning API permissions to User Assigned Managed Identities is not possible through Portal. You have to use PowerShell to assign permissions.

Comment: Do you know how do I get a Brear token for that API permission using DefaultAzureCredential in C#? or should it be a separate question?